# Where to grind for complete decks?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

In MTG 2014, each deck you unlock comes with only 10 out of 40 cards unlocked. To complete the deck, you ought to win several games, each win unlocking an additional card. For 22 decks, including the expansion, that sums up to 660 wins total.
A grinding strategy seems to be advisable.

Since the campaign levels vary a lot, each deck would perform best at a different level, I assume.

So: What would be a good/best level to gain additional cards for each deck?

A google search is of little use, I get mostly sealed-deck strategies. Maybe my Google-Fu is too weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grinded against ENCOUNTER 2 - SKIRSDAG CULTISTS.

Basically you mulligan for an easy first couple of turns and a board clear spell. Don't let the opponent get 6 cultists on the field because they will sacrifice them for a big demon. Although you can potentially let them sacrifice them for a demon if you have hard removal.

After you get past the first sac'ed demon, they basically only play cultists. I found it very boring, but the fastest way to gain the additional cards.

Comment: Did you have any problems with heavier/slower decks?

Comment: @npst No not really. You basically have 3-4 turns before you start taking any serious damage. The cultists are only 1/1 creatures. This encounter has no other buffing spells or anything like that that you have to worry about. If you can get a 2/2 minion out on turn 3 or even turn 4 you can start blocking basically for free and keeping the enemy from sacking into a demon :)